# state not reflecting updates immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, use-effect, use-state

I hope this won't get flagged as a duplicate because none of identical problems reflect my issue totally.
So the issue i'm having is i have a useEffect hook like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        
         console.log("opening websocket");
         websocket.current=new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/${curMessage.receiverUsername}/${curUserName}/`);
         websocket.current.onopen= (event)=>{
             console.log("open:",event)
         }
         websocket.current.onclose= (event)=>{
            setSentMessages([]);
            console.log("close:",event,sentMessages);
        }


        websocket.current.onmessage=(event)=>{
            console.log("new message",event);
            console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
            setSentMessages([...sentMessages,JSON.parse(event.data)]);
            setCont([...cont,1,2]);
            console.log(sentMessages);
            

        }
        
        
        
       setSentMessages([]);
        
    },[curMessage,curUserName]);
```

the variable `curMessage` gets it value from redux state and since it's in the dependency array in the useEffect changes should be reflected immediately the changes are made in the redux state,this work correctly except for the `setSentMessages([])` at the last line in the useEffect,the state `sentMessages` never gets updated immediately the useEffect is triggered which results to still getting old values instead of an empty array,everything else works fine and updates in the useEffect when it gets triggered,i have tried making placing `setSentMessages([])`  in another useEffect which is dependent on another state but still the same result.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you open a new WebSocket on every message received. Shouldn't it be done only once in the mounting hook?

Comment: Shouldn't `sentMessages` be in the dependency array as well?

Comment: @timotgl it shouldn't because it will cause the useEffect to be called infinitely,you can't update a state in a useEffect in which the state is added to the dependency array

Comment: @MihaiMatei not on every message received,the useEffect will get triggered when i'm changing my current chat from user A to user B like on Whatsapp if you want to leave a current user chat to another user, pardon me if my explanation is poor

Comment: Isn't changing the chat partner something the user actively does? Why not run all this logic in that moment instead of letting a useEffect catch it?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [sentMessages, setSentMessages] = useState([
    // some initial state here
]);

const sentMessagesRef = useRef([
    // some initial state here
]);

useEffect(() => {
  // Keep ref in sync with state    
  sentMessagesRef.current = sentMessages;
}, [sentMessages]);

useEffect(
  () => {
    websocket.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      // Use up-to-date value of sentMessages here,
      // not the value at the time of declaring this function.
      setSentMessages([...sentMessagesRef.current, JSON.parse(event.data)]);
    }
    
    setSentMessages([]);
  },
  [curMessage, curUserName]
);
```

I believe your issue is that `setSentMessages([])` is in fact working, but the `onmessage` function then overwrites that state with the outdated value. The state **is** updated immediately, but your callback uses a stale reference of `sentMessages`. Copying the state to a ref and then accessing that fixes it.